# PySpark Crossvalidation error

Tags: cross-validation, pyspark

I want to do a very simple cross validation using LogisticRegression.
Here is my code:

```
logreg = LogisticRegression(labelCol = "churn", featuresCol = "features") 

pipeline = Pipeline(stages = [logreg])
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(logreg.regParam, [.1, .01]).build()

crossval = CrossValidator(
    estimator = pipeline,
    estimatorParamMaps = paramGrid,
    evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
    numFolds = 2)

bestLogReg = crossval.fit(df_train)
```

When I run this, I get the following error on `bestLogReg = crossval.fit(df_train)`:

`IllegalArgumentException: label does not exist. Available: features, churn, CrossValidator_764038c00edc_rand, rawPrediction, probability, prediction`

Here is my `df_train` dataset's schema:

```
root
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- churn: integer (nullable = true)
```

I have fit this to a LogisticRegression before and it predicts fine.

Can you help me figure out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason in cross validation we also need to set the label column of the evaluator (even tho it's already set for the estimator. So all you need to do is change `BinaryClassificationEvaluator()` into `BinaryClassificationEvaluator().setLabelCol("churn")` where "churn" is the name of your target variable.